# error in refreshing element which contains ajax results in the unseen pages

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

so basically what i do is , while user is in the first page i try to get and put content to other pages , i need to call refresh on the element so i don't lose css but i keep getting errors in this part . it's always the page which user is not in that gives me the error

html

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul  data-role="listview" class="news_list"></ul> </div>
   </div>
```

calling function

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        get_latest_news( 1 , 'http://www.xxx.com' , 0 );
    })
```

main function

```
function get_latest_news(id , link_ , refresh_ ){


        var w = $('#'+id).find('.wrapper');
        w.hide();
        w.find('.news_list').html('');
       jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url :  link_ ,  
            success:function(data){
                var ul ='' ;
                  $.each( data.posts , function ( k , v ){
                        ul += '<li><h3><a href="#each_news">'
                        +v.title+'</a></h3>'+
                        '<p > '+v.date+' </p></li>';
                    });
                    w.find('.news_list').append(ul);
                    w.find('.news_list').listview('refresh');
                    w.show();
            } 

        })

    }
```

i get

```
Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

in this line

```
w.find('.news_list').listview('refresh');
```

i change it to

```
 w.find('.news_list')listview().listview('refresh');
```

now i get

```
TypeError: parentPage[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

parentId = parentUrl || parentPage[ 0 ][ $.expando ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is **`document ready`**, it can't be used to initialize **`jQuery Mobile`** code. It will trigger before **`jQuery Mobile`** can load pages into the **`DOM`**. That's why **`jQuery Mobile`** has its own way of initializing content, and it is called page events:

Lets say you have a page with an id **`index`**, you would initialize it like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    //Call your ajax here
});
```

To find more about **`jQuery Mobile`** page events, and how they work take a look at my **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

Your code should look like this in case you have a page with an id index:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
    get_latest_news( 1 , 'http://www.xxx.com' , 0 );
});
```

[**pagebeforeshow**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) is an event you want to use here because it will trigger before page is about to be shown, so there's enough time to trigger **`AJAX`** call and populate listview before page is shown.

Other page events can be found **[HERE](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)**.